# How to check if a radio button is checked without names or ids in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to see the value of all the radio buttons without using names or ids, but whenever I try getElementByID the objects I get are just unidentified.

EDIT: I only want to useJavaScript, I don't know any jQuery

```js
function getData() {
  var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input type="radio"');
  var inputList = Array.prototype.slice.call(input);
  for (radio in input) {
    if (radio.checked)
      console.log(radio.value + " is checked");
    else
      console.log(radio.value + " is not checked");
  }
}

function toggleButton() {
  this.checked = true;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label> radio button 1 
<input type="radio" onclick="toggleButton()" value="radio button 1"> 
  </label>
  <label>
   radio button 2
<input type="radio" onclick="toggleButton()" value="radio button 2">
  </label>
  <label>
   radio button 3
<input type="radio" onclick="toggleButton()" value="radio button 3">
  </label>
</form>
<button onclick="getData()"='submit'>Run Scripts!</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using only plain JavaScript and a `<form>` but no `#id`,`.class`, or `[attribute]` to hook into, use [**HTMLFormControlsCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection).

**Details are commented in Demo**

### Demo

```js
// Reference the first <form> 
var form = document.forms[0];

// Register form to the change evemt callback is getData()
form.addEventListener('change', getData, false);

// Register form's fourth form control (<button>) to click event
form.elements[3].addEventListener('click', getData, false);

function getData(e) {
  // Collect all of form's form controls into a HTMLCollection
  var rads = form.elements;

  /* if the clicked node (e.target) [type] attribute is "radio"
  || or "button"...
  */
  if (e.target.type === "radio" || e.target.type === "button") {

    // Loop through the rads HTMLCollection
    for (let r = 0; r < rads.length - 1; r++) {

      // if this particular rad ('radio button') is checked...
      if (rads[r].checked) {
        console.log(rads[r].value + " is checked");
      } else {
        console.log(rads[r].value + " is unchecked");
      }
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<form>
  <label> radio button 1 
<input type="radio" value="radio button 1"> 
  </label>
  <label>
   radio button 2
<input type="radio" value="radio button 2">
  </label>
  <label>
   radio button 3
<input type="radio" value="radio button 3">
  </label>
  <button type='button'>GetStatus</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Why aren't you accessing it's value instead of using a counter?

Answer (score 2):

There may be other issues here, but the reason you are not getting what you are looking for is because of this line:

```
var input=document.getElementsByTagName('input type="radio"');
```

You need to select your elements like so:

```
var input = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
```

**UPDATE:**  It doesn't matter how you loop over your array (or in this case, a NodeList technically), but you need to treat it like an array somehow.  You are trying to use a `for in` loop, which is for objects.  If you want to use `forEach` you can update your code like so:

```
function getData() {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
  inputs.forEach( function (radio){
      if (radio.checked)
      console.log(radio.value + " is checked");
    else
      console.log(radio.value + " is not checked");
  });
}
```

Comment: querySelectorAll didn't work, it is still returning undefined. Is it because I'm not using forEach?

Comment: Just added to my question.  You are not getting `undefined` with the selector I described.  If you had used `console.log` to debug, you would have seen that.  You need to inspect your code at every step as you learn to program. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have identified the following issues with your script:

1. `getElementsByTagName` expects a tag name as the argument. It cannot work on CSS selectors (which is in fact also wrong in your question).
2. To loop on the selected elements, you should use `Array#forEach` on `inputList`, and not on `input` directly.

Correcting these, following is a working example of your code:

```js
function getData() {
  var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var inputList = Array.prototype.slice.call(input);

  inputList.forEach(function(radio) {
    if (radio.checked)
      console.log(radio.value + " is checked");
    else
      console.log(radio.value + " is not checked");
  });
}

function toggleButton() {
  this.checked = true;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label> radio button 1 
<input type="radio" onclick="toggleButton()" value="radio button 1"> 
  </label>
  <label>
   radio button 2
<input type="radio" onclick="toggleButton()" value="radio button 2">
  </label>
  <label>
   radio button 3
<input type="radio" onclick="toggleButton()" value="radio button 3">
  </label>
</form>
<button onclick="getData()"='submit'>Run Scripts!</button>
```

Comment: How would this work if I wanted to add other types of inputs, such as check boxes, and I wanted to differentiate between the different types?

Comment: Also apart from looping over the wrong var, what is wrong with using a for loop as opposed to using forEach?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use jQuery to select inputs with same name and then select the checked value
2. Use `getElementsByName` to select all inputs (get a NodeList). Convert it to array, and then filter it return the checked value

```js
function getData1() {
  const input = $('input[name="contact"]:checked').val()
  console.log(input);
}

function getData2() {
  const inputs = Array.from(document.getElementsByName('contact'));
  const val = inputs.filter(i => i.checked)[0].value;
  console.log(val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="radio" id="contactChoice1" name="contact" value="email" checked>
  <label for="contactChoice1">Email</label>

  <input type="radio" id="contactChoice2" name="contact" value="phone">
  <label for="contactChoice2">Phone</label>

  <input type="radio" id="contactChoice3" name="contact" value="mail">
  <label for="contactChoice3">Mail</label>
</form>
<button onclick="getData1()">Run jQuery version!</button>
<button onclick="getData2()">Run vanilla JS version!</button>
```

Comment: How are you getting it to only have one selected at a time? Also I want to do it without any names or Ids

Comment: @JonathanHuang I set the 1st one to checked in HTML. Since they shared same name (*Not id, id must be different*), it will work automatically.